# Get sender email in email composition on Office add-in

Tags: javascript, office365, outlook-addin

I build a Office add-in for Outlook.

I would like to get sender email like recipient in composition.

For get recipient i use this function : item.to.getAsync. However, "from" attribute is empty.

It's just a question of right or forbidden ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You juste have to use [Office.context.mailbox.userProfile](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.userProfile)

Answer (score 0):

The sender related attributes are filled in only after the message is sent.

Comment: Thanks. Why after sent ? I want add tracking. It's not possible to get this information before with others process ?